# VueJS, expressJS, axios DELETE error: Request failed with status code 404

Tags: javascript, vue.js, express, axios, vuejs3

I am learning basics of making **MEVN** stack application and have some issue with **axios** DELETE request.

The problem is, that when I make DELETE request with axios, it gives `Request failed with status code 404`.

**Request example**: `DELETE http://localhost:9999/item/123`;

**Full error in inspector**:

```
XHR DELETE http://localhost:9999/ [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 5ms]

Object { message: "Request failed with status code 404", 
         name: "AxiosError", 
         code:         "ERR_BAD_REQUEST", 
         config: {…}, 
         request: XMLHttpRequest, 
         response: {…}, stack: "" }
```

(*Notice, that in the error I have no part `item/123`, I don't know why*)

I know, that **Error 404** means that file/document not found and in most cases problem in **incorrect route path**. It seems, that i have not the last one.

**To the code**

**vue js**; file `MEVN_testing/src/App.vue`, part with DELETE request:

```
DeleteItem(item) {
  axios
    .delete(`http://localhost:9999/item/${item.id}`)
    .then((res) => {
      console.log("DELETE request done...", res.status);
      this.UpdateList();
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
```

Here I want to make DELETE request to server with URL template `http://localhost:9999/item/item_id`

**express js**; file `MEVN_testing/server/src/routes/routes.js`, DELETE request handler:

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();

const itemModel = require("../models/itemModel.js");

...

router.delete("/:id", (req, res) => {
    itemModel.findOneAndDelete({ id: req.params.id });
    res.redirect("/");
});

...

module.exports = router;
```

Here I just want delete item with given *id* from mongodb database.

**express js**; file `MEVN_testing/server/src/index.js`, creating app:

```
const path = require("path");
const express = require("express");

const PORT = 9999;
url = `http://localhost:${PORT}/`;

const urlencodedParser = express.urlencoded({ extended: false });

const app = express();

app.use(express.json());
app.use(urlencodedParser);

// Including build vue app as static files to route /
app.use("/", express.static(path.join(__dirname, "..", "..", "dist")));
// using routes and bind it to route /item
app.use("/item", require("./routes/routes.js"));

console.log(url);
app.listen(PORT);
```

In the last one `app.use("/item", require("./routes/routes.js"))` I "including" `routes.js` file and defining all paths of that route to begin with `/item` address.

What can cause this problem?
Thank you.

Comment: can you console log item.id

Comment: @AlaaKaddour, `console.log(item.id)` returns 123 in inspector, when click on item with corresponding id=123

Comment: so let's try to change the ${item.id} by 123 and see if it works

Comment: @AlaaKaddour, already tried. Same result. If leave url `http://localhost:9999/item`, then don't remove /item part, and of course 404, because I have no such route.

Comment: @AlaaKaddour, i tried request with query `http://localhost:9999/item/?id=${item.id}`, in `router.delete(...)` it have query parameters `{ id: '123' }`, but  error the same with error displayed `XHR DELETE http://localhost:9999/`

Comment: that's a path params not a query params , so let's debug the router .

Comment: write console.log(app._router.stack) before the app.listen ....

Comment: and can you replace the router.delete with router.get and open the same url in browser , http://localhost:9999/item/123

Comment: @AlaaKaddour, when make `console.log(app._router.stack)` return list of objects (Layer), which one you need? With replaced delete on get it works, I get `id` from `req.params.id`

Comment: @AlaaKaddour, in all objects in `console.log(app._router.stack)` field `route` is `undefined`.

Comment: did you test the get one

Comment: @AlaaKaddour, yes, if replace DELETE with GET (and change route method correspondingly), it works fine and delete item without any error with `status code 200`

Comment: replace res.redirect(.....) with return res.send('DONE')

Comment: @AlaaKaddour, replacing `res.redirect(.....)` to `res.send('DONE')` helped. Have no error with DELETE request. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was, that I used `res.redirect("/")`.

(I suppose, that in this case, the application doesn't get a response from server, which causes an 404 error)

**Solution:**

replace `res.redirect("/")` with `res.send("some message")`